# Docx4J get header/footer elements from docx file and modify them

Tags: java, xml, docx, docx4j

I am using Docx4J to modify docx templates and put values in place of placeholders in the template that are predefined.

so far, i had been successful in finding and replacing paragraphs and texts, tables, images etc. But i am not yet successful in finding Header and/or Footer elements of the document.

I am using

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage =
WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
```

to search for elements in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your application, you can mimic the code in https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/BindingHandler.java at line 145

A similar approach is taken in https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/fields/merge/MailMerger.java at line 124

Comment: The updated link for the first link: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/7736f3358f6ec38e7ac10dba8a49a691ea72f716/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/BindingHandler.java

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to replace keyholders on the footer(In Java, no XML). The piece that I was missing is the :

```
JaxbXmlPart part = (JaxbXmlPart) relationshipPart.getPart(r);
```

from the source-code [MailMerger.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/fields/merge/MailMerger.java) that [JasonPlutext](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031689/jasonplutext) mentioned, stated in the line 410. So thank you [JasonPlutext](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031689/jasonplutext)!

```
public static void replaceElementFromFooter(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String nameplace, String placeholder, String newValue) throws Docx4JException {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    RelationshipsPart relationshipPart = template.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart();

    List<Relationship> relationships = relationshipPart.getRelationships().getRelationship()

    for (Relationship r : relationships) {

        if (r.getType().equals(nameplace)) {

            JaxbXmlPart part = (JaxbXmlPart) relationshipPart.getPart(r);

            List<Object> texts = getAllElementsFromObject(part.getContents(), Text.class);

            replaceTextElement(texts, placeholder, newValue);
        }

    }

    return result;
}

private static List<Object> getAllElementsFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) {
        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();
    }

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch)) {
        result.add(obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
        for (Object child : children) {
            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void replaceTextElement(List<Object> texts, String placeholder, String newValue) {
    for (Object element : texts) {
        Text textElement = (Text) element;

        if (textElement.getValue().contains(placeholder)) {
            String replacedValue = textElement.getValue().replaceAll(placeholder, newValue);
            textElement.setValue(replacedValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search and replace in the XML you can use:

```
String xpath = "//w:r[w:t[contains(text(), 'placeholder')]]";
List<Object> list = wordMLPackage.getHeaderFooterPolicy().getDefaultHeader().getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);
list.addAll(wordMLPackage.getHeaderFooterPolicy().getDefaultFooter().getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false));
```

The list contains all the nodes where the placeholder is present. After you can get the type of the placeholder (text, picture ...) with the method I explain here (it's for text but easy to adapt):
[replace_placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938012/docx4j-xml-how-to-get-the-value-of-a-jaxbnodes)